# I want to fetch all JIRA release versions to confluence, How can i fetch all versions to confluence macro and show with custom view

Tags: macros, jira, confluence, jira-rest-api

I want to create Confluence plugin which fetches JIRA issues,
I know there is already one macro which fetching issues but my use case is different so I have to create own confluence macro.

JIRA has rest APIs for all issues, I don't understand how to integrate rest API and authentication in confluence macro.

What are the ways to fetch JIRA release version to confluence page.
Is there any sample code or tutorials which exactly shows integration between Confluence and Jira with customization.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a broad question.

Assuming you're working with a Confluence server version, you'll have to write a Confluence plugin and implement your custom macro. There is some [documentation available here](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/macro-module/writing-macros?_ga=2.201031661.231522245.1500978251-2010682879.1500978251).

Your plugin will require that there's an Application Link from Confluence to JIRA. There are java API classes that allow you to retrieve the application links in your plugin. Using the application link you can get an ApplicationLinkRequestFactory that allows you to send REST API requests to the application you're targeting, ie. JIRA.

Then you can use JIRA's REST API to retrieve the info that you need and provide a template for your macro that displays the info the way you like it.

Relevant docs:

- [ApplicationLinkService](https://docs.atlassian.com/applinks-api/3.2/com/atlassian/applinks/api/ApplicationLinkService.html)
- [ApplicationLink.createAuthenticatedRequestFactory()](https://docs.atlassian.com/applinks-api/3.2/com/atlassian/applinks/api/ApplicationLink.html)
- [SAL API RequestFactory](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/shared-access-layer/sal-services)
- [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/project-getProjectVersions): GET /rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/versions

Related questions:

- [Get Credentials from Current User in Atlassian Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140653/get-credentials-from-current-user-in-atlassian-plugin/45302531#45302531)
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/What-is-the-recommended-way-to-send-REST-requests-from-a-custom/qaq-p/568227

Comment: If you can get all the versions, create a user macro as described here https://davidsimpson.me/2014/06/23/jira-release-user-macro-atlassian-confluence/ and loop through the versions.